# downloadable weights of VGG-16 during ImageNet training

Tags: conv-neural-network, weights

Does anybody know a place from where it is possible to download the
weights of VGG-16 at different epochs, along a succesful training on ImageNet?

The ideal situation would be to have downloadable weights at a few checkpoints along training (like epoch 0, 10, 20, etc.) until completion, in order to 
follow the evolution of the network and to study its behavior during the evolution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the framework you are using, but here's few popular ones:

- caffe - https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo#models-used-by-the-vgg-team-in-ilsvrc-2014
- tf/keras - https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/vgg16.py
- pytorch - https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.0/_modules/torchvision/models/vgg.html

I don't know if anyone released weights at multiple checkpoints of training, and I doubt if anything like would be available from the "official" repos of these frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Indeed this is exactly the problem. Usually these weights are not available with these frameworks API and we should rely on the good will of our peers :)